# Match only valid UTF-8 characters

Tags: rust, ncurses

I'm writing an ncurses app with Rust.

When the user inputs a valid UTF-8 char (like `ć`, or some Asian letters), I want to build up a search string from it and print it to screen. Currently I have this:

```
use ncurses::*;

fn main() {
    ...
    let mut search_string = String::new();
    ...
    loop {
        let user_input = getch();
        match user_input {
            27 => break,
            KEY_UP => { ... },
            KEY_DOWN => { ... },
            KEY_BACKSPACE => { ... },
            _ => {
                search_string += &std::char::from_u32(user_input as u32).expect("Invalid char.").to_string();
                mvaddstr(0, 0, &search_string);
                app::autosearch();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, this catches all other keys, such as `F5`, `KEY_LEFT`, etc.

How can I match only valid UTF-8 letters?

Comment: And what do you want to do for invalid characters?

Comment: @mcarton Ignore all invalid characters.

Comment: when input can be utf8 characters, you should to use get_wch function, when it is possible

Comment: ANSI escape sequences are valid UTF-8 encoded strings though.

Comment: `get_wch()` still doesn't get `ć` in its entirety.

Comment: That might be because of Unicode grapheme clusters — characters that consist of _multiple_ unicode scalar values. I'm not sure if/how well ncurses supports them.

Answer (score 0):

If `getch` gives you a `u8`, you could collect subsequent key presses into a `Vec<u8>` and then call e.g. [`from_utf8`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8) on each `getch`, handling the error as appropriate (see [`Utf8Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Utf8Error.html) for more info).

Comment: I'm not sure how many times should I call `getch()`, and where. Is there like a null byte that `getch()` returns so I can stop calling `getch()` when I encounter such a thing? I think you really should show a code example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a start, you could just call `from_utf8` on each char, and try to find out from the potential `Utf8Error` how often you need to call it.

Answer (score 0):

In C, you could call `get_wch()` instead of `getch()` -- it returns `KEY_CODE_YES` for KEY_* codes, while the actual key is stored to an address passed as a parameter. But I don't know how this translates to Rust.